# How to send a text file to this C program?

Tags: c

I want to send my text file to this code. How can I do this?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char charNow,lastChar;
    int totalNumber =0,countOrNot =1,countOrNot2=0, flagSlash =0, cCount=0;
    int  position=0,quotesOnOff =0,sOnOf = 0, charSeek,lines=0, i=0,wrong=0,flag=0;
    if (file == NULL)
        return printf("Invalid file");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    int code[size];

    while ((charNow = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre], explain what specific issue you have with it and ask a specific question. Please also take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes the 1st argument is a file to be read so either have the sending program write that file, or if you are on Linux you can use /dev/stdin as the filename and have the sending program pipe it to your program:

```
./sender | ./receiver /dev/stdin
```